# List extension modules without importing all

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Using dir(module) will list all the dot options for my module however, some modules require you to explicitly import it before being able to view it in the directory.

How would I be able to see all extensions of the module without having to run

```
from modulename import *
```

I.e.

```
>>>import sklearn
>>>dir(sklearn)
['__SKLEARN_SETUP__',
 '__all__',
 ...
 ...
 'sys',
 'utils',
 'warnings']
```

AFTER

```
>>>import sklearn.tree
>>>dir(sklearn)
['__SKLEARN_SETUP__',
 '__all__',
 ...
 ...
 'sys',
 'tree', #Now it has been added to the list
 'utils',
 'warnings']
```

Comment: Have you looked into [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: ``sklearn.tree`` is a module. It literally does not exist to Python before importing it. You would have to rebuild large parts of the import machinery to reproduce module discovery. Note that packages can change the search path for submodules - these must be imported to reproduce the import behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the inspect module has a nice way of doing this!

```
import inspect

inspect.getmembers(modulename)[1] # [1] gives us the stuff we want
```

For the sklearn case:

```
>>>inspect.getmembers(sklearn)[1]

('__all__',
 ['calibration',
  'cluster',
  'covariance',
  ...
  ...
  'svm',
  'tree',  # There she is
  'discriminant_analysis',
  'impute',
  'compose',
  'clone',
  'get_config',
  'set_config',
  'config_context',
  'show_versions'])
```